# how to poll for messages from AMQ queue at every 30 minutes Mule-4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

can some one guide me on this.  when ever a message fails in flow we are dropping that in Dead Letter Queue. I need to reporesess the message daily once. For this reason I need to poll the queue daily once at some time. I am using JMS consume with the following configuration [image]

But it is polling for every second or less than that. I need to poll the queue for message at a given interval of time. if I increased wait time then it is throwing time out error after specified time.

```
<jms:consume doc:name="Consume" doc:id="e63155ec-7563-4409-bd83-c66e6e1c792a" config-ref="AMQ-DocuSign-Connector" destination="${amq.docusign.reports.bqueue}" maximumWaitUnit="SECONDS" maximumWait="0">
            <jms:consumer-type>
                <jms:queue-consumer />
            </jms:consumer-type>
        </jms:consume>
```

any help is much appreciated

edit:
even using scheduler at source of the flow is not working. here is the code for reference

```
<flow name="message-reprocessing-reports-subflow" doc:id="f3ffe923-ee3e-4e0d-8a29-ec874b9755d7" >
        <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler" doc:id="ff715c36-be3e-4f79-bdc9-db7934c75985" >
            <scheduling-strategy >
                <fixed-frequency frequency="${jms.message.reprocessing.polling.interval.in.seconds}" startDelay="${jms.message.reprocessing.polling.initial.delay.in.seconds}"/>
            </scheduling-strategy>
        </scheduler>
        <set-variable value="${amq.docusign.reports.bqueue}" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="a521f360-8722-4e84-a5da-6b90f51d437b" variableName="blockQueue" />
        <jms:consume doc:name="Consume" doc:id="e63155ec-7563-4409-bd83-c66e6e1c792a" config-ref="AMQ-Connector" destination="${amq.bqueue}" maximumWaitUnit="SECONDS" maximumWait="0"><jms:consumer-type><jms:queue-consumer /></jms:consumer-type></jms:consume></flow>
```

Comment: You can set jms.message.reprocessing.polling.interval.in.seconds to 86400 and I believe this will work once per day.  However, when I use this pattern I drain the queue by using a recursive flow-ref, and the jms:consume timeout is used to detect that the queue is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JMS Consume operation is not intended to be used that way. It expects to read a message when executed. The time that you are increasing is just a time out. It doesn't poll for messages. Instead to read message at your desired time only you can put the `<jms:consume>` operation inside a flow and put a [Scheduler](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/scheduler-concept) source to trigger that flow. Set the Scheduler to the desired frequency.

```xml
<flow name="pollJMS" >
  <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler" >
    <scheduling-strategy>
      <fixed-frequency frequency="30" timeUnit="minutes"/>
    </scheduling-strategy>
  </scheduler>
  <jms:consume ... />
</flow>
```

Comment: thanq this is working my bad I have set the time units in milliseconds instead of seconds